# contacts frame work using objective c step by step procedure

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have made a program [you may see 4 vc's] it adds the data to the tables in sqlite and also displays data in tableview. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A187.png)

furthure i have made a button add phone contacts as follows[the vc is connected to the add phone contacts button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6GFT.png)

now from here i need to know each and every step for adding my phone contacts or contacts from my mac to get displayed in the stimulator.

Comment: Check out this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-import-contact-address-book/

Comment: address book is deprecated.